# Terraform - what is the URI to invoke lambda via alias?

Tags: aws-lambda, terraform

## Question

To invoke a Lambda from API GW, [invoke_arn](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/lambda_function.html#invoke_arn) can be used for aws_lambda_function resources.

> invoke_arn - The ARN to be used for invoking Lambda Function from API Gateway.

```
resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "videos" {
  rest_api_id = "${aws_api_gateway_rest_api.24_hour_video.id}"
  resource_id = "${aws_api_gateway_method.videos_get.resource_id}"
  http_method = "${aws_api_gateway_method.videos_get.http_method}"

  integration_http_method = "GET"
  type                    = "AWS_PROXY"  # Lambda Proxy
  uri                     = "${aws_lambda_function.list_videos.invoke_arn}"
}
```

What is to set in **uri** to invoke the same lambda via an alias?

```
resource "aws_lambda_alias" "lambda_alias_list_videos" {
  name             = "get_video_list"
  description      = "Alias to lambda_list_videos"
  function_name    = "${aws_lambda_function.list_videos.arn}"
  function_version = "$LATEST"
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `aws_lambda_alias` resource creates an alias which points to a specific version of a Lambda function. The alias itself is not invocable.

Instead you should create an `aws_lambda_function` Data Source that points to the aliased version, and use its `invoke_arn` property. You can use the `qualifier` argument in an `aws_lambda_function` to specify either a version or an alias name (see [AWS Lambda Invoke Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_Invoke.html#API_Invoke_RequestSyntax) for more info).

Your example shows you have already created an alias named *get_video_list*, which points to the *$LATEST* version. You need to create a new Data Source that points to this alias:

```
data "aws_lambda_function" "my_function_get_video_list" {
  function_name = "your-function-name"
  qualifier = "get_video_list"
}
```

You can now get the invocation ARN of the aliased function:

```
${aws_lambda_function.my_function.get_video_list.invoke_arn}
```

Comment: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lambda_function.html does not have qualifier attribute. Is the answer content correct?

Comment: That's the doc for the Resource. It is the Data Source that has the qualifier attribute https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/d/lambda_function.html

Answer (score 5):

`aws_lambda_alias` resource has `invoke_arn` attribute (see [docs](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/r/lambda_alias.html#invoke_arn)) which is designed for API Gateway. For example:

```
resource "aws_lambda_alias" "api_function_alias_live" {
  name             = "live"
  function_name    = aws_lambda_function.api_function.function_name
  function_version = "1"
}

resource "aws_api_gateway_integration" "proxy_integration" {
  rest_api_id             = aws_api_gateway_rest_api.api_gateway.id
  resource_id             = aws_api_gateway_resource.proxy_resource.id
  http_method             = aws_api_gateway_method.proxy_method.http_method
  integration_http_method = "POST"
  type                    = "AWS_PROXY"
  uri                     = aws_lambda_alias.api_function_alias_live.invoke_arn
}
```